# Could UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification get my app rejected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm observing `UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification` on `UINavigationController` to keep track when the current view controller has been popped, as suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236380/how-to-determine-what-the-prior-visibleviewcontroller-in-uinavigationcontrollers/2021970#2021970) post.

There's literally no reference anywhere for that notification and a Google search will link me only to that post.

Does it mean this is a private notification and my app could be rejected?

Even worse: does it mean I shouldn't trust how that notification works as it might break in a future SDK version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification in question is actually implicitly referenced in the documentation:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Delegate methods are, at least in Cocoa for Mac OS X usually accompanied by a notification (well, often times, anyway).

As it stands it's an undocumented feature, and as such should be treated with care. If possible, use the delegate method instead.

**However:** If it appears in the header, and it works, *and* it is accompanied with a delegate method; it is possible that this is a documentation oversight on Apple's side; and that using it is safe.

I recommend filing a bug and see where that gets you; at least if restructuring your application to use a delegate directly would be overly cumbersome (more cumbersome than filing a bug).

Comment: And if one were really paranoid about this falling under the "private API" umbrella, he/she could implement the delegate method and then fire a custom notification for other objects to observe.

Comment: Don't even need to be a custom one; it could just be `UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification`. :)

Comment: The notification itself doesn't appear on the headers - there's no constant for it, I'm using an actual NSString for it's name. And, actually, this is different from the delegate method. When I get the notification, the navigation stack is still intact and I have on the user info dictionary both the last visible navigator and the next visible navigator. So I have which view controller is being popped from the stack - something I can't do with the delegate method alone.

Comment: File a bug, then. It's clearly and undocumented feature, but it might not be by design. Even if only two applications so far need it, it does appear to be fully functional. Here I think the best is to ask Apple for clarity.

Comment: I shipped (and updated at least 3 times) an app with this notification, and Apple never rejected it. It's very useful if you want to make something happen every time any navigation controller is shown, like playing a sound for example.